# Laurent series of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$ for the region $\{1<|z-1|\}$? Here it seems trivial but I might be wrong. I put it as it is, am I correct? That means its Laurent series must be itself $\frac{1}{z-1}$.

Comment: Your answer sounds good.

Comment: @Jake... Thanks!

Comment: The Laurent expansion in an annulus is unique. See for instance [here](https://planetmath.org/uniquenessoflaurentexpansion).